# Плавное выезжающее меню

Tags: html, css, css3, css-animation

Как сделать , чтобы меню плавно выезжало сверху вниз?

```js
var trigger = $('.mobilem');

menu = $('header .bottom__header .nav');
trigger.on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
  $('header .bottom__header').toggleClass('open');
  menu.toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
header .wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

header .top__header {
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

header .top__header .container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
  align-content: center;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 100%;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 100%;
  flex: 0 1 100%;
}

header .top__header .box-info {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
  align-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header .top__header .btn-bgreen {
  font-size: 24px;
}

header .bottom__header {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  padding: 5px 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.mobilem {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  z-index: 8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mobilem:after {
  content: attr(data-label);
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 38px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.mobilem.open:after {
  content: attr(data-label-close);
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 38px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.mobilem ._line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 24px;
  height: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #222;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.mobilem ._line.__1 {
  bottom: 16px;
}

.mobilem ._line.__2 {
  top: 16px;
}

.mobilem.open ._line.__1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  bottom: 0;
}

.mobilem.open ._line.__2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.mobilem.open ._line.__3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 0;
}

header .bottom__header .nav {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 10200;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  top: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  right: auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: .5s;
}

header .bottom__header .nav li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
  &:before {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

header .group__header .nav__header .nav a {
  font-size: 20px;
}

header .bottom__header .nav a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  color: #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #f6f8fd;
}

header .bottom__header .nav li .sub {
  padding: 0;
  li {
    a {
      padding-left: 30px;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
  }
}

header .bottom__header .nav a.active {}

header .bottom__header .nav.open {
  height: max-content;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="top__header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="box-info">
          <div class="mobilem" id="mobilem">
            <span class="_line __1"></span>
            <span class="_line __2"></span>
            <span class="_line __3"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom__header">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="">Услуги</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Прайс</a></li>
          <li><a href="">О компании</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Проекты</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Контакты</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Отзывы</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Это так не работает, приведите минимальный пример а все что не относится к вопросу уберите подальше, создайте новый html и css и начните все с чистого листа, затем добавьте в ваш код

Comment: отредактировал вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать трюк с `max-height`

```js
var trigger = $('.mobilem');

menu = $('header .bottom__header .nav');
trigger.on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
  $('header .bottom__header').toggleClass('open');
  menu.toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
header .wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

header .top__header {
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

header .top__header .container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
  align-content: center;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 100%;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 100%;
  flex: 0 1 100%;
}

header .top__header .box-info {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
  align-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header .top__header .btn-bgreen {
  font-size: 24px;
}

header .bottom__header {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  padding: 5px 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.mobilem {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  z-index: 8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mobilem:after {
  content: attr(data-label);
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 38px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.mobilem.open:after {
  content: attr(data-label-close);
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 38px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.mobilem ._line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 24px;
  height: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #222;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.mobilem ._line.__1 {
  bottom: 16px;
}

.mobilem ._line.__2 {
  top: 16px;
}

.mobilem.open ._line.__1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  bottom: 0;
}

.mobilem.open ._line.__2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.mobilem.open ._line.__3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 0;
}

header .bottom__header .nav {
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 10200;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  width: 300px;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  right: auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: 2s all;
}

header .bottom__header .nav li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
  &:before {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

header .group__header .nav__header .nav a {
  font-size: 20px;
}

header .bottom__header .nav a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  color: #000;
  border-top: 1px solid #f6f8fd;
}

header .bottom__header .nav li .sub {
  padding: 0;
  li {
    a {
      padding-left: 30px;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
  }
}

header .bottom__header .nav a.active {}

header .bottom__header .nav.open {
  max-height: 900px;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="top__header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="box-info">
          <div class="mobilem" id="mobilem">
            <span class="_line __1"></span>
            <span class="_line __2"></span>
            <span class="_line __3"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom__header">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="">Услуги</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Прайс</a></li>
          <li><a href="">О компании</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Проекты</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Контакты</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Отзывы</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```